# Can't post to Twitter from my iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios4, twitter

I'm using this small chunk of code to post in Twitter, with real credentials in place of 'mytwitterloginname' and 'mytwitterpassword' placeholders:

```
void _StartTwitter()
{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mytwitterloginname:mytwitterpassword@twitter.com/statuses/update.xml"] 
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

    // The text to post
    NSString *msg = @"testing";

    // Set the HTTP request method
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"status=%@", msg] 
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    if ([NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                              returningResponse:&response error:&error] != nil)
        NSLog(@"Posted to Twitter successfully.");
        else 
            NSLog(@"Error posting to Twitter."); 
}
```

But even my console says the post was succeful it still doesn't happen.

Can anyone help me to find what's wrong ?, thanks.

Comment: You need to inspect the response object being returned. Just because a connection is successful doesn't mean the requested action was successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I though twitter had only O-AUTH authentication now, so you couldn't post information simply through their REST service anymore.

You may need to re-integrate with their new OAUTH service.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the link to the OAUTH Examples:
 [Twitter - OAUTH](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554657/OAuth-Examples)

The bummer part that I needed to do was create a WebUI view in order to go through the silly steps twitter now enforces.  After doing a request to authenticate (which is bound to an app created in twitter), my session was created and from there I could do my posting of a message.

Not nearly as user friendly as the previous REST service :/

Comment: Didn't know that. Gonna search some info about the OAUTH autentication or an actualized Twitter tutorial. Thanks.